# How do I rotate the icon based on the isActive state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do have the icon component like that:

```
<Styled.Icon
          color={isActive ? activeColor : color}
          activeColor={activeColor}
        >
          <Icon name="arrowDown" />
        </Styled.Icon>
```

I need to rotate this icon based on the isActive state. How can I do this in styled components? I tried something like this:

```
export const Icon = styled.div`
  ${(isActive) =>
    isActive &&
    `
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    `}
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
`
```

But it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can't you just use css? like: #arrowDown:active {transform: rotate(180deg)} ? (first you have to add "arrowDown" id to Icon element)

Comment: Hi, for this particular project i am using styled components and it is a bit different... Arrow down is hard coded in react components and needs to be rotated based on the isActive state. I speciffically need ot use this with transform: rotate(180deg);. Can you please advise how can I do this based on the isActive and styled components?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a props to your component called `isActive` as an example and then based on its value you set the css transform value.

```
<Styled.Icon
      isActive={isActive}
>
<Icon name="arrowDown" />
</Styled.Icon>

export const Icon = styled.div`
   transform: ${props => props.isActive ? "rotate(180deg)" : "rotate(0)"};
   padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
`
```

here is how to adapt your style based on the props from the official [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props).

Comment: Hi, Any idea why it is not working? It seems that this is applying to the styles in general, not only when the styles are active. And I need this icon to be rotated always when the color is active and when state is set to active.